# Why can´t I click on the JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Hey I am a beginner and I have wrote the following code in java, but I can´t click on the JButtons. The program includes three clases - Main, Frame and Actionhandler. My goal was to create a Frame with two buttons: Singleplayer and Mulitplayer. I wanted to test if they work, but I can´t click them. Can anyone help me please?

This is the Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
         new Frame ();  
    }
}
```

This is the Frame class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public static Object multi;
    public static Object single;
    Frame() {
        
        // Frame 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);           
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        //Layout in Frame
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        // Buttons in Main Menu
        JButton single = new JButton("Singleplayer");  
        JButton multi = new JButton("Multiplayer");                                                              

        // specify single button
        single.setBounds(200,100,250,80);
        single.setForeground(Color.GREEN);                                           
        single.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        single.setOpaque(true);
        single.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        single.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans",Font.BOLD,25));  
        single.addActionListener(new ActionHandler());
        
        //specify multi button 
        multi.setBounds(800,100,250,80);
        multi.setForeground(Color.GREEN);                                            
        multi.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        multi.setOpaque(true);
        multi.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans",Font.BOLD,25));  
        multi.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        multi.addActionListener(new ActionHandler());
        

        // add Buttons to Frame
        this.add(single);
        this.add(multi);  
    }
}
```

This is the ActionHandler class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public  class ActionHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == Frame.multi) {
        System.out.println("You have clicked on Singleplayer");

        if(e.getSource() == Frame.single) {
            System.out.println("You have clicked on Multiplayer");
        }
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can click on the buttons fine. They just won't do anything because of how you've wired the program:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public static Object multi; // this is null
    public static Object single; // and so is this
    
    Frame() {
        
        // Frame 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);           
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        //Layout in Frame
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        // Buttons in Main Menu
        JButton single = new JButton("Singleplayer");  // this is a new *local* variable
        JButton multi = new JButton("Multiplayer");    // and so is this:
```

You are initializing *local* variables that have the same name as your static class fields, and you're leaving the same static class fields null, a situation known as "variable shadowing", and so in your listeners, you check if the source is the null static field. Which won't work.

So in your listener:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == Frame.multi) {
```

You're testing if a null variable is the button that was pressed, and this will not work.

One simple solution is to not re-declare the multi and single variables, to assign your JButtons to these public static fields by changing this:

```
JButton single = new JButton("Singleplayer");  
JButton multi = new JButton("Multiplayer");
```

to this:

```
single = new JButton("Singleplayer");  
multi = new JButton("Multiplayer");
```

This would sort-of work. You'd have do do some casting to add these JButton objects to the container since the variables are Object, not JButton. But this would be a *bad* idea because you'd be throwing out the OOPs baby with the bathwater, discarding encapsulation completely.

Best not to throw out OOPs rules with public static (non-constant) fields and instead work with them. Better to use constant Strings to be passed into your JButtons and then test for them using the ActionEvent's actionCommand property:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {
    public static String SINGLE_PLAYER = "Single Player";
    public static String MULTI_PLAYER = "Multi Player";
    
    Frame() {
        // Frame 
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);           
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        //Layout in Frame
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        // Buttons in Main Menu
        JButton single = new JButton(SINGLE_PLAYER);  // this is a new *local* variable
        JButton multi = new JButton(MULTI_PLAYER);    // and so is this:
```

in the listener:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public  class ActionHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals(Frame.MULTI_PLAYER)) {
            System.out.println("You have clicked on Multi Player");
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }};
}
```

Other problems with your code include:

- Don't name your class `Frame` since this clashes with the name of class in the core Java library, `java.awt.Frame`. Name it something unique to avoid confusion
- Avoid setting bounds, sizes and such. Let the GUI, its layout managers and component preferred sizes do the sizing by calling `pack()` on the top-level window (JFrame, JDialog,...) after adding components
- Call `.setVisible(true)` on the top-level window *after* adding all components.
- This looks like it will display as a sub-window or dialog window, and you might want to show this portion of the GUI in a modal JDialog, not in a JFrame.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks!!